# WSO2 EMM dafault redirect

Tags: redirect, console, default

I just successfully run WSO2 EMM product and it’s really nice solution.
I have one question regarding default redirect to console. When I type server address in the browser  ex.  emm.abc.com  I’m automatically redirect to carbon console, how can I change it to redirect users to EMM console or to application store?

Thanks in advanced for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

type the address like 192.168.1.1:9443/emm or store or publisher 
and it will work